# Alfresco: Finding out the type of a piece of content

Tags: alfresco

When I log into `http://localhost:8080/alfresco` I can navigate to a folder and see four content items. So far so good. But there is no indication as to what the type is of each content type, except for a PDF icon.

**Is there a way for me to specify an icon for my custom content types?**

I would like the icon to be dependent on my custom type.

```
<types>
    <type name="sc:doc">
        <title>Someco Content</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
        <icon>boring-icon.png</icon>            <-- something like this
    </type>
    <type name="sc:marketingDoc">
        <title>Marketing Document</title>
        <parent>bnp:doc</parent>
        <icon>fancy-marketing-icon.png</icon>    <-- something like this
    </type>
</types>
```

If it matters, I am using Alfresco 3.3 (Enterprise).

Comment: do you want to have a custom icon depending on the Alfresco content type like cm:content or depending on the mimetype like application/pdf?

Comment: I'd like it based on the create content Type drop down selected.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/tasks/kb-code-explorer-add.html
e.g.  web-client-config-custom.xml (sc:marketingDocis the Alfresco content type):

```
   <!-- Specify icon for the kb:document instances -->
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="sc:marketingDoc icons">
      <icons>
         <icon name="sc_marketingDoc-icon" path="/images/icons/your_custom_icon.gif" />
      </icons>
   </config>
```

Are you informed, that Alfresco Explorer is deprecated & you should use Share instead?

Comment: I was not aware that it had been officially deprecated. I do like what I have seen of Share, but unforunately time constraints are pushing us to use Alfresco Explorer.